# Python Tkinter placing frame and treeview within a notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am working on a very simple TKinter layout. It is comprised of a notebook with two tabs. In the first tab I have 1 Frames and inside that 3 more. This works fine and can be seen below :

[image: Notebook in frame with 3 frames]

However, when I try to add a Treeview to the left most red box (confusingly called top_frame). It just sits underneath.

Like the below:

[image: With Treeview]

I think I have the parent child relationships correct, so can not see why it is not sitting as intended.

Any help welcome. My code is below and I need the result to place the treeview in to the red box. I have spent a long time trying to fix this having started out using grid() within the notebook but still no luck even when switching to pack()

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) 
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
  
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1') 
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2') 
tabControl.pack()




top_frame1 = Frame(tab1, bg='red', width = 450, height=400, relief=SUNKEN).pack(side=LEFT, fill = BOTH)
Mid_frame = Frame(tab1, bg='Orange', width = 450, height=100, relief=SUNKEN).pack(side=RIGHT, fill = BOTH)
bottom_frame = Frame(tab1, bg='green', width = 450, height=100, relief=SUNKEN).pack(side=RIGHT, fill = BOTH)

treeview_menu = ttk.Treeview(top_frame1)
treeview_menu.pack()
treeview_menu.insert('','0','m1', text = 'department 1')
treeview_menu.insert('','1','m2', text = 'department 2')
treeview_menu.insert('','2','m3', text = 'department 3')
treeview_menu.insert('','3','m4', text = 'department 4')
treeview_menu.insert('','4','m5', text = 'department 5')

treeview_menu.insert('m1','end','cs1', text = 'Staff Mbr1')
treeview_menu.insert('m1','end','cs2', text = 'Staff Mbr2')

treeview_menu.insert('m2','end','bc1', text = 'Staff Mbr1')
treeview_menu.insert('m2','end','bc2', text = 'Staff Mbr2')

treeview_menu.insert('m3','end','av1', text = 'Staff Mbr1')
treeview_menu.insert('m3','end','av2', text = 'Staff Mbr2')

treeview_menu.insert('m4','end','mc1', text = 'Staff Mbr1')
treeview_menu.insert('m4','end','mc2', text = 'Staff Mbr2')

treeview_menu.insert('m5','end','ss1', text = 'Staff Mbr1')
treeview_menu.insert('m5','end','ss2', text = 'Staff Mbr2')
```

Comment: `top_frame1`, `Mid_frame`, and `bottom_frame` are not what you think they are. They are all `None`.

Comment: thanks @BryanOakley. I checked this out and it made sense. Kicking myself, So many hours wasted. When I get a chance I will post a solution. Happy for you to do it so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I just ran into this and there still is not an accepted answer.

```
top_frame1 = Frame(tab1, bg='red', width = 450, height=400, relief=SUNKEN).pack(side=LEFT, fill = BOTH)
Mid_frame = Frame(tab1, bg='Orange', width = 450, height=100, relief=SUNKEN).pack(side=RIGHT, fill = BOTH)
bottom_frame = Frame(tab1, bg='green', width = 450, height=100, relief=SUNKEN).pack(side=RIGHT, fill = BOTH)
```

.pack does not return the object.  Since these are all on the one line the variable is never actually set. Thus bottom_frame, mid_frame, and top_frame all return None.

The variable must be set from the Frame() function and then call the pack() function.

```
top_frame1 = Frame(tab1, bg='red', width = 450, height=400, relief=SUNKEN)
top_frame1.pack(side=LEFT, fill = BOTH)
Mid_frame = Frame(tab1, bg='Orange', width = 450, height=100, relief=SUNKEN)
Mid_frame.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = BOTH)
bottom_frame = Frame(tab1, bg='green', width = 450, height=100, relief=SUNKEN)
bottom_frame.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = BOTH)
```